# django templatetags for jquery to get item from html templatetag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-template-filters

I have photo album for this site I'm working on and am using jquery to filter by country/city. If I hardcode in each country into the jquery I get my desired results. I obviously do not want to do this. Below is what I mean by that.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="photo-title">
        <h1>Welcome to Our Photo Album</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 photoalbum-buttons">

        <div class="dropdown form-actions">
            <button class="btn btn-primary gradient dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                By Country
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><button id="all_countries" value="all_countries">All Countries</button></li>
                {% for obj in object_list %}
                    <li><button id="{{ obj.country }}" value="{{ obj.country }}">{{ obj.country }}</button></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown form-actions">
            <button class="btn btn-primary gradient dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                By City
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                {% for obj in object_list %}
                    <li><button id="{{ obj.city }}" value="{{ obj.city }}">{{ obj.city }}</button></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="all-photos-div">
        <div class="dropdown form-actions hidden-div">
            <button id="all_photos" class="btn btn-primary gradient dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                All Photos
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p id="photo-separator">______________________________________________</p>

    <div class="row">
       <div class="row photo-post">
            {% for obj in object_list %}
                <div class="col-sm-3 country_{{obj.slug}}">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="#" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-title="{{ obj.city }}, {{ obj.country }} {% if obj.picture_taken %}| {{ obj.picture_taken }}{% else %}{% endif %}" data-caption="{% if obj.picture_description %}{{ obj.picture_description }}{% else %}{% endif %}" data-image="{{ obj.pictures.url }}" data-target="#image-gallery">
                            <img class="img-responsive pic-height" src="{{ obj.pictures.url }}" alt="Short alt text">
                        </a>
                        <div class="caption photo-description">
                            <p class="photo-location">{{obj.city}}, {{obj.country}}</p>
                            <p class="photo-time">{% if obj.picture_taken %}{{ obj.picture_taken }}{% else %}{% endif %}</p>
                             <p>
                                 <a class="thumbnail btn btn-primary" href="#" type="button" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-title="{{ obj.city }}, {{ obj.country }} {% if obj.picture_taken %}| {{ obj.picture_taken }}{% else %}{% endif %}" data-caption="{% if obj.picture_description %}{{ obj.picture_description }}{% else %}{% endif %}" data-image="{{ obj.pictures.url }}" data-target="#image-gallery">
                                    View
                                 </a>
                             </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
                    <div class='col-sm-12'><hr/></div></div><div></div><div class='row'>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

And my jquery to filter:

```
$(function(){
    $("div.dropdown.form-actions > ul.dropdown-menu > li > button#Greece").click(function(){
        $("#all-photos-div").show() & $("#all_photos").show();
        $(".country_Greece").show();
        $(".country_Germany").hide();
        $(".country_Scotland").hide();
        $(".country_united_states").hide();
    });
});
$(function(){
    $("div.dropdown.form-actions > ul.dropdown-menu > li > button#Germany").click(function(){
        $("#all-photos-div").show() & $("#all_photos").show();
        $(".country_Germany").show();
        $(".country_Greece").hide();
        $(".country_Scotland").hide();
        $(".country_united_states").hide();
    });
});
$(function(){
    $("div.dropdown.form-actions > ul.dropdown-menu > li > button#Scotland").click(function(){
        $("#all-photos-div").show() & $("#all_photos").show();
        $(".country_scotland").show();
        $(".country_greece").hide();
        $(".country_germany").hide();
        $(".country_united_states").hide();
    });
});
$(function(){
    $("div.dropdown.form-actions > ul.dropdown-menu > li > button#Scotland").click(function(){
        $("#all-photos-div").show() & $("#all_photos").show();
        $(".country_scotland").show();
        $(".country_greece").hide();
        $(".country_germany").hide();
        $(".country_united_states").hide();
    });
});
$(function(){
    $("#all_photos").click(function(){
        $("#all-photos-div").hide() & $("#all_photos").hide();
        $(".country_greece").show();
        $(".country_germany").show();
        $(".country_scotland").show();
        $(".country_united_states").show();
    });
});
$(function(){
    $("#all_countries").click(function(){
        $("#all-photos-div").hide() & $("#all_photos").hide();
        $(".country_greece").show();
        $(".country_germany").show();
        $(".country_scotland").show();
        $(".country_united_states").show();
    });
});
```

So, I am using templatetags in the html to get the Country names and city names (though I am getting duplicates, which I'll correct after this issue), but am hardcoding the country names(slugs) into the jquery. I have tried using templatetags in the jquery, however this doesnt seem to work.

My question: How can I capture the filter button's value in the `$("button#{{ country }}").click(function()`... then also show all pictures with that country while hiding the others? I'm going to stick with jquery or js, and not use ajax. Mainly because I dont have enough time to learn ajax, regardless of how simple I hear. I'll look into that next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ID tags to identify your image blocks and give them the same class name.

So your HTML could look like this with changes to the `button` tag and your `photo-post` class.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="photo-title">
        <h1>Welcome to Our Photo Album</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 photoalbum-buttons">

        <div class="dropdown form-actions">
            <button class="btn btn-primary gradient dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                By Country
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><button id="all_countries" value="all_countries">All Countries</button></li>
                {% for obj in object_list %}
                    <li><button id="{{ obj.country }}" value="{{ obj.country }}">{{ obj.country }}</button></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown form-actions">
            <button class="btn btn-primary gradient dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                By City
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                {% for obj in object_list %}
                    <li><button id="{{ obj.city }}" value="{{ obj.city }}">{{ obj.city }}</button></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="all-photos-div">
        <div class="dropdown form-actions hidden-div">
            <button id="all_photos" class="btn btn-primary gradient dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                All Photos
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p id="photo-separator">______________________________________________</p>

    <div class="row">
       <div class="row photo-post">
            {% for obj in object_list %}
                <div class="col-sm-3 country-name-class" id="country_{{obj.slug}}">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="#" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-title="{{ obj.city }}, {{ obj.country }} {% if obj.picture_taken %}| {{ obj.picture_taken }}{% else %}{% endif %}" data-caption="{% if obj.picture_description %}{{ obj.picture_description }}{% else %}{% endif %}" data-image="{{ obj.pictures.url }}" data-target="#image-gallery">
                            <img class="img-responsive pic-height" src="{{ obj.pictures.url }}" alt="Short alt text">
                        </a>
                        <div class="caption photo-description">
                            <p class="photo-location">{{obj.city}}, {{obj.country}}</p>
                            <p class="photo-time">{% if obj.picture_taken %}{{ obj.picture_taken }}{% else %}{% endif %}</p>
                             <p>
                                 <a class="thumbnail btn btn-primary" href="#" type="button" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-title="{{ obj.city }}, {{ obj.country }} {% if obj.picture_taken %}| {{ obj.picture_taken }}{% else %}{% endif %}" data-caption="{% if obj.picture_description %}{{ obj.picture_description }}{% else %}{% endif %}" data-image="{{ obj.pictures.url }}" data-target="#image-gallery">
                                    View
                                 </a>
                             </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
                    <div class='col-sm-12'><hr/></div></div><div></div><div class='row'>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

Change jquery to this

```
$(function(){
    $("div.dropdown.form-actions > ul.dropdown-menu > li > button").click(function(){
        var country = $(this).attr(id);
        $(".country-name.class").hide();
        $("#country_"+country).show();
});
```